# How to get data from array object in angular typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, httpclient

I am calling a rest api which returns the data in json array of object format like this
[image]

Now when I call this rest api from my typecsript code and print on console data received i get this

`gameRecord: Fifa = new Fifa();` // this is defined globally in ts class

```
this.fifaService.fetchGameRecord(gameId).subscribe(
          data => {
            this.gameRecord = data;
            console.log(this.gameRecord);
          }
        );
```

[image]

Now I want to get the wonBy, kashScore attributes value from this object.

**But I get undefined error on console, I don't know why**

```
gameRecord: Fifa = new Fifa();


this.fifaService.fetchGameRecord(gameId).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.gameRecord = data;
        console.log(this.gameRecord.kashScore);
      }
    );
```

Here Code Definations,

```
export class Fifa {

    gameId: number;
    kashScore: number;
    samScore: number;
    wonBy: string;
    createUserId: number;
    lastModifiedUserId: number;
    creationDate: Date;
    lastModifiedDateTime: Date;
    sessionId: number;
}
```

And my service file code

```
fetchGameRecord(gameId: number): Observable<Fifa>{
    const fifaUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/getGameDetail/${gameId}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Fifa>(fifaUrl);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gameRecord: Fifa = new Fifa();

```
this.fifaService.fetchGameRecord(gameId).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.gameRecord = data[0]; // <= data is an array
        console.log(this.gameRecord.kashScore);
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

here data is an array of type `Fifa` objects, not single object

so you can access it like `this.gameRecord[0].kashScore`
Also you might need to update `gameRecord: Fifa = new Fifa()` this statement if you are expecting more records in the array as this.gamerecord will be array of objects else you can access the 0th element of array every time